# How can I add rows to an SQL table without knowing how many column it has

Tags: sql

I'm building an attendance system that tracks attendance in an SQL table.
I do this by adding a new column of a date to the table every time it's used.
now I have a problem adding new rows for new users because I don't know how many columns I have so I cant use INSERT INTO Table VALUES().

Is there any alternative way to do it?

Edit:
here's how it's supposed to look
[image]

and every day it's supposed to add a column for the date.
I don't   really understand how can I do it with adding dates as rows
can someone elaborate?

Comment: Get the idea that adding a new column is not the right way to do this then?  There should be no reason to add a new column to the table.  Your method should just be adding *rows* not *columns*.

Comment: Why are you adding a column every time it's used? Normally you would design your table with set columns and add a row for each record.  Can you show us the table and columns so we can get see what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: "*adding a new column of a date to the table every time it's used*" - as Gordon and David already told you: this is the wrong approach.

Comment: I have added a picture maybe now you'll understand better

Comment: How do you add _a new column of a date to the table_?

Comment: Abra "ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD   date   bit"

Comment: @Amit as already pointed out, adding columns is the wrong approach. But a column that only contains a true/false value should be defined as `boolean`, not `bit`

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I don't know how many columns I have_ Query the data dictionary view [USER_TAB_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/USER_TAB_COLUMNS.html#GUID-7DAA74E5-E165-49C8-9D4B-5701C876C28B)

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name  there is no boolean type in this SQL version. and I  read  that  bit is used as a de facto boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should probably tweak the design of your tables. Using the example of a school:

```
Student Table:
ID (Primary Key)
Name
(More student specific columns here)

Attendance Table:
ID (Primary Key)
StudentID (Foreign Key)
Date
Attended
TimeArrived
(More Attendance specific columns here)
```

In the above example, each day would get a new row added to the attendance table and you could avoid dynamically adding columns.

Comment: So for each day  I add a new row for every student?

Comment: Yes, this will also make your queries easier for when you try to retrieve information from the database.

Comment: You don't actually need the `id` column for the `attendance`. The primary key can simply be `(student_id, date)`